# Why should you revoke access token?

Tags: authentication, oauth, jwt, openid-connect, refresh-token

I don't understand why should you revoke Access Token when your log out. I mean what should you gain from a security perspective, while there is a Refresh token which is used to get a new access token as soos as you browse to the application?
I don't see the profit from a security perspective when there is a Refresh token which can be used by whoever uses the computer and browse to the application.

Answer (score 3):

Whilst the concept of OAuth 2.0 is based on short lived access tokens that are not revoked, there are exceptions to that rule and there's a protocol specification catering for token revocation, RFC 7009 OAuth 2.0 Token Revocation https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7009.

When revoking the access token, one should also make sure to revoke the refresh token at the same time (the spec dictates that revoking a refresh token will also revoke associated access tokens). This becomes more important when tokens are long lived and there's a suspicion of some breach, unauthorised 3rd-party token access or other token leakage.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't understand why should you revoke Access Token when your log out.

Access tokens cant be revoked. They are used for Authorization, and grant the bearer of the access token access to the data for as long as the token has not expired.

Logging out is Authentication these are two very different concepts.

> I mean what should you gain from a security perspective, while there is a Refresh token which is used to get a new access token as soon as you browse to the application?

You are again mixing Authorization (OAuth 2.0 access token refresh token) with authentication(open id connect, logging in a user).

Using OAuth 2.0 an application is granted authorization to access a users data they are granted an access token and a refresh token.  The application can access the users data when ever it needs to without the user being present.

> I don't see the profit from a security perspective when there is a Refresh token which can be used by whoever uses the computer and browse to the application.

This is the exact point of OAuth 2.0 it is there to grant an application access to a users data when the user is not present.  It is not authentication.

Comment: Do you mean that you revoke refresh token, not access token? what happens to these two tokens when you log out?

Comment: Nothing those two tokens have nothing to do with being logged in or logged out.    Refresh token use used for OffLine access to the users data when they are not logged in.   You should have an IdToken if you are using open Id connect that denotes the user is Logged in.

Comment: "Refresh tokens carry the information necessary to get a new access token. In other words, whenever an access token is required to access a specific resource, a client may use a refresh token to get a new access token issued by the authentication server."

Comment: Which has again nothing to do with login an authentication as the user doesn't need to be there

Comment: yes, but my question is if I logout and leave my computer, and then somebody else come and use my computer to browse to the application, what happend? Does the refresh token makes it possible for intruder to be able to use my computer to browse to the application and use it to access my data? because the refresh token is there, beacuse he doesn't need to log in again and get a new access token.

Comment: When you log a user out of your Application, you should be removing all session variables and or cookies off of their machine.  Then when they login again you reset them.  I cant say what you are using for a login system wither or not your storing the refresh token as a cookie or a session var.

Answer (score 1):

When a user logs out from an OAuth2-based session, they might want to make sure that every application on the same machine can no longer do things on a users' behalf.

For example, perhaps your organization has a single-sign on system that spans several applications, some even third party. When the user logs out, you can't rely on applications to 'log themselves out'. Perhaps all they got is a a session cookie, sitting in a browsers' cookie jar waiting for the next request.

If I log out on a machine, I want the guarantee that nothing can still act on my behalf, not even for a minute.